# what is difference between console.time() vs Date.now() in javascript and which one is better performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, console.log

I have written some nodejs code and I am logging api call response timing.
console.time() and Date.now() but I am not sure which one is better in performance and right to use.

Answer (score 1):

Date.now() just returns the number of milliseconds from the linux Epoch, whereas
`console.time()` is a shortcut to be used together with `console.timeEnd()`, normally used for measuring the time that takes some operation, for example:

```js
console.time()
doSomething()
console.timeEnd()
```

The output will be something like:

```
default: 7042.885ms
```

You can read more about it here:https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_time_label